# Skipping solution folders in TT automation script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte, texttemplate

I have a Text Template snippet which generates a `Solution` class with an `Assemblies` property to list all project assemblies in the Visual Studio solution to help with IoC container configuration ([GitHub](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/x-utils/blob/master/X.VisualStudio/Solution.tt), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/X.VisualStudio/1.0.0-CI00002)). It fails when projects are placed in solution folders though. How to make solution folders transparent for this script? The problematic code is:

```
<#+

    class SolutionAssemblyNames : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        public SolutionAssemblyNames(ITextTemplatingEngineHost host)
        {
            Host = host;
        }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => Assemblies.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerable<string> Assemblies => Projects
            .Select(p => p?.Properties?.Item("AssemblyName")?.Value as string)
            .Distinct().Where(a => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a));

        IEnumerable<Project> Projects => VisualStudio.Solution.Projects.OfType<Project>();
        DTE VisualStudio => (Host as IServiceProvider).GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
        ITextTemplatingEngineHost Host { get; }
    }
#>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DTE doesn't return a flat list of projects, so you need to proactively check for solution folders and then read its sub-projects, recursively (as you can have solution folders inside solution folders, etc.)

```
    IEnumerable<string> Assemblies => Projects
        .SelectMany(GetProjectAndSubProjects) // ################# Flatten the list of projects
        .Select(p => p?.Properties?.Item("AssemblyName")?.Value as string)
        .Distinct()
        .Where(a => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a));

    IEnumerable<Project> Projects => VisualStudio.Solution.Projects.OfType<Project>();

    private static IEnumerable<EnvDTE.Project> GetProjectAndSubProjects(EnvDTE.Project project)
    {
        if (project.Kind == VsProjectKindSolutionFolder)
        {
            return project.ProjectItems
                .OfType<EnvDTE.ProjectItem>()
                .Select(p => p.SubProject)
                .Where(p => p != null)
                .SelectMany(GetProjectAndSubProjects);
        }

        return new[] { project };
    }

    // Copied from EnvDTE80.ProjectKinds.vsProjectKindSolutionFolder
    private const string VsProjectKindSolutionFolder = "{66A26720-8FB5-11D2-AA7E-00C04F688DDE}";
```